# Can wavefunctions be real?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

I remember proving that real wavefunctions have zero expectation value for momentum and don't define any useful physical states. But still for a particle in infinite potential well the wavefunction is given as $\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}} \sin (\frac{n\pi}{a}x)$  which is real...What is the reason for this?

Comment: "zero expectation value" for what observable? Is it reasonable for that observable to have an expectation value of zero?

Comment: When you say *real wavefunctions have zero expctation value and dont define any useful physical states* are you thinking of the infinite plane wave? If so then yes these don't represent physical states because they cannot be normalised. But this doesn't mean all states are unphysical - just infinite plane waves.

Comment: sorry i think i accidently deleted momentum  while editing

Comment: It looks like you already have your answer then. You have a conjecture "Real wavefunctions are physically 'useless' (whatever useless means in this context)". And you have provided a counter-example: the real wavefunctions of the infinite potential well.

Comment: so real wavfunctions have physical sense or is it that particle in a box itself is no sensible physical state which is it?

Comment: because i think particle in a box is supposed to be free to move whereas a real WF with zero expectation for momentum forbids any sor of movement

Comment: "useful physical states" is not a well-defined class ─ you need to provide your own definitions; in this case, you need to be *extremely* clear about what you mean by that term.

Comment: Zero expected value for momentum doesn't mean that expected value for square of momentum is also zero. Recall that e.g. uniformly distributed random variable on $[-1,1]$ has also zero expected value, despite the value $0$ having zero probability.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}} \sin (\frac{n\pi}{a}x)$ is just the spatial dependency.  Recall that all stationary states have a temporal factor of $e^{-i E t/ \hbar }$.  Multiply these to obtain $\psi(x,t)= e^{-i E t/ \hbar }\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}} \sin (\frac{n\pi}{a}x) $.

Edit: why the downvote?  OP clearly thought the ISQ wavefunction was *"all real"* in the sense of *"zero expectation value for momentum and don't define any useful physical states."*  But that isn't true.  Useful physical states exist due to the $e^{-i E t/ \hbar }$ factor.